# $C^3$ monotone spline interpolation

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, spline

I am looking for a spline interpolation that is 3 times differentiable, strictly monotone and doesn't involve the inclusion of extra control nodes. I found this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097849300000534) that describes the construction of monotone rational cubic splines in $C^2$, but I can not find any method that constructs $C^3$ splines. I don't care about the degree of the polynomial, just that it can be constructed without introducing extra points and that the monotonicity conditions are given in closed form.
Is there any work you can point me to or is this an open problem?

Comment: Any spline with single knots and degree of 4 or more is going to be C3. Now you just have to worry about monotonicity.

Comment: Yes, but the monotonicity is exactly what gives me trouble. There seem to have been many papers written about this topic, but they usually are restricted to $C^2$ splines

Comment: There are very few (if any) applications that require curves to be C3, so it’s not surprising that the literature is so sparse.

Comment: When it comes to math, there is always a first for an application at some point :D I found I-Splines, they seem to be doing what I want as they can be chosen to be arbitrarily differentiable and are monotonically increasing

Comment: @LucaThiede could you give us the reference for the I-Splines please ? I am also searching for a C3 monotone spline...

Comment: There isn't many references to it except for the Wikipedia article, I don't think they were used very much
The Wikipedia article is understandable enough to implement it though